# Will parameter of a static object's non-static method be shared from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

(All of the below are simplified for brevity)

I have a static reference to a processing object.

The Processor contains a function to which I can pass an object Package, which is the info to be processed.

The Package comes from a list of lots of packages which should be processed. These packages are unqique; there are not multiple references to the same object here.

I start many threads so that I can process the packages in toProcess in parallell. The threads Pop() an available Package from the toProcess stack until the stack is empty.

My question is now: Can I risk that `package` in `Check` is overwritten by another thread, or will the other thread "create a copy" of `Check`?

```
static class Program
{
    static Processor processor = new Processor();
    static Stack<Package> toProcess;
    static Object sync = new Object();

    static void RunThreads()
    {
        toProcess = GetPackages();
        //start many threads using the Work delegate
    }

    static void Work()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Package p;
            lock(sync)
            {
                if(toProcess.Count == 0)
                   break;
                p = toProcess.Pop();
            }
            processor.Check(p);
        }
    }
}

class Processor
{
    public void Check(Package package)
    {
        //do many analyses on p and report results of p's analysis to elsewhere
    }
}

class Package
{
    //properties
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is now: Can I risk that package in Check is overwritten by another thread, or will the other thread "create a copy" of Check?

It's not really clear what you mean, but each independent call to `Check` will have its own `package` variable. That variable is local to not just that thread, but that invocation of `Check` (so recursive calls won't change it either).

Now if you pass the same `Package` reference to `Check` in multiple different threads, then yes, they will all be processing the same object, which may cause problems. But the `package` variables *themselves* will be independent in the different calls.

Comment: This answered my doubts. I should have clarified that all Package references in the toProcess stack points to different objects (i.e. all references in toProcess are unique and not modified elsewhere). My doubt was exactly whether the `package` parameter itself in `Check` is independent in calls from multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

If `Package` is a `class`, i.e. a reference type, and if in `Check` you execute some write operation, yes - you *will* have to manage access to it with locking mechanism.

On the other hand: if `Package` is a value type, it will be passed to the function *by value*. If `Check` only *reads* information (even if `Package` is a reference type), then there is no need to worry about locking.

Comment: How can another thread corrupt Package when it's local variable of static method? New Package will be created each time.

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy: it's not a local variable, it's a part of the Stack<..> which is *static global* variable.  And thread runs *Work(..)* function..

Comment: Yes but Pop will remove it from stack and as far this operation is locked no other thread will have acces to it.

Comment: @Tigran: Well, `package` *is* a local variable of the `Check` method. It's a parameter, and its value can't be affected by other threads. The data *within the object that value refers to* can be changed, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy: yes but that *p* object refernce can point to exactly same *p* object changed in another thread. Am I clear ?

Comment: @JonSkeet: that is actually what I'm talking about. And that's why, in this case, OP's would need to manage locking mechanism here.

Comment: @Tigran Yes but p is local method variable (not static field) its not shared between threads. New p reference will be created for each thread. Have I missed somethig?

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy: yes, new reference can be created, but these different refernces *can* point to the **same** memory, to the **same** object data, so if one change a property of *its p*, that change will be "visible" from other *p* as they all point to the same memory location.

Comment: @Tigran: Well, that's why I said the OP's question isn't clear. The OP asked if the `package` *variable* could be overwritten in a different thread - and that *can't* happen.

Comment: @Tigran I do agree with you that it possible but not in code provided in question. Here new package can be obtained from stack only and Pop operation is locked. So how it can be possible (with current code) that two threads get refference to same package object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you warrant that a package of your stack cannot be Popped from multiple thread, there should no problem as long as none of the package in your stack are the same.

However, you should perform locking in your `Check` method if it changes the `Processor`'s state.